# C# MYSQL Updating only one field that is empty from C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

I have been working on a school project and my program inserts, alter, deletes, everything I want to! But there's still a problem.

Basically I have a table named Costumer with the fields:

**ID, Name, e-mail, phone, blacklist.**

Blacklist is set as bool and what I want to do is:

I created a form named blacklist where people can insert the "**ID**" in a textbox and after that the blacklist  field is set to "**TRUE**".

I have this:

```
("ALTER TABLE Cliente (blacklist)  WHERE ID Like '" + txtid.Text + "VALUES('" + TRUE + "')'");
```

Comment: `UPDATE` is for update and `ALTER` to change the table structure, What is your intent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this query:

```
UPDATE Costumer
SET blacklist = "TRUE"
WHERE ID = Id
```

As an additional note since you are entering user input directly into your query you want to use paramertized queries to prevent `SQL Injection`.

For example:

```
 command.Text = "UPDATE Costumer SET blacklist = 'TRUE' WHERE ID = @CostumerId";
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostumerId", txtid.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Costumer  set blacklist='true' WHERE ID ='" + txtid.Text +"'";